# Function for finding the length of a curve connecting two points in a two-dimensional sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to study differential geometry.

I am confused with regards to the following function for finding the length of
a curve $\gamma$ connecting two points $p, q ∈ S^2$

$$L(γ) = \int^1_0|\dot{γ}(t)| dt,γ(0) = p, γ(1) = q$$

Where $S^2$ is a 2-dimensional sphere sitting in the three dimensional Euclidean space $R^3$

I am unfamiliar with the "dot above function" notation (dot above $\gamma$), what does it mean? And from where is this function derived or what is it called?

Answer (score 0):

$\dot{\gamma}(t)$ is the same as $\gamma’(t)$ . The dot notation is called Newton’s notation of the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

As @math.pr said the **dot** shows drive function. But about formula, if you take an eleman on curve and assume to be straight, so its length can be computed by euclidean meter as below:
$$dL=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2} \Longrightarrow \int dL = \int \frac{\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}}{dt} \ dt \Longrightarrow$$
$$L = \int \sqrt{\frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{dt^2}} \ dt = \int \sqrt{\frac{dx^2}{dt^2}+\frac{dy^2}{dt^2}+\frac{dz^2}{dt^2}} \ dt = \int \sqrt{(\frac{dx}{dt})^2+(\frac{dy}{dt})^2+(\frac{dz}{dt})^2} \ dt$$
$$= \int \left|\left(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt}\right)\right| dt = \int \left| \overset{.}{\gamma}(t) \right| dt \Longrightarrow L = \int \left| \overset{.}{\gamma}(t) \right| dt$$
And the limits show the start and end points.